# cx_Freeze generated EXE prints no Console output

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am facing a difficulty compiling Python script with cx_Freeze 5.0.
The script compiles correctly, EXE is generated. Before all the requirements were met, a series of error messages were printed to the console.
After adding all requirements, **running the EXE makes no output to console**. The program stops silently without printing anything.
If run directly from Python it works as expected:

```
>python testScript.py -p 12 aaa/bbb.ccc
Test script with the following params:
Namespace(input_file='aaa/bbb.ccc', param=12)
```

I think the issue is related to *argparse* package I use.

Below is a little test script and compile script I wrote that reproduces teh behaviour.

```
from sys import exit, argv
import os
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=os.path.basename(argv[0]),
        description='Command line parser test.')
    parser.add_argument('input_file',
                        metavar='path/to/file',
                        help='path to source file)')
    parser.add_argument('-p','--param', required=False,
                        metavar='par',
                        type=int, default=1,
                        help='test parameter')

    try:
        args = parser.parse_args()
    except argparse.ArgumentError:
        exit("Use -h option for help on using.")

    if args.input_file is None:
        parser.print_usage()
        exit(0)

#%% display parameters
    print "Test script with the following params:"
    print args
```

cx_Freeze compile script:

```
from cx_Freeze import version, setup, Executable
import sys

print "Compilation using cx_Freeze version", version

productName = "testScript"

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["sys","os","argparse"]}

exe_options = Executable(
                          script = productName+".py",
                          targetName = productName+".exe",
                          base = None
                         )
setup(
      name=productName,
      version="0.0",
      author="mstankie",
      description="test script",
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables=[exe_options]
)
```

Why the program prints nothing to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't related to *argparse*... Finally I tried printing the contents of `__name__`. It seems, if run directly from Python interpreter the variable contains `'__main__'`, but

**the variable `__name__` when run as cx_Freeze-compiled EXE, contains `'nameofthegeneratedexe__main__'` string.**

Changing the line `if __name__ == "__main__":` (no. 5 in the listing above) to:

```
if "__main__" in __name__:
```

solved the issue.

Comment: This was a bug in cx_Freeze which has just been resolved by the release of cx_Freeze 5.0.1 today.